# Create calendar with C++Builder

Tags: calendar, c++builder

I am creating a calendar app with C++Builder using the following view:

[image]

But I want to create a calendar which  includes the following view:

[image]

Comment: And your question is ...? The same WinRT calendar component handles both views. So what are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: I want this view be default view when i execute program

Answer (score 1):

The [`TCalendarView` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCalendars.TCalendarView) states:

> CalendarView displays the month view by default, **but allows you to configure a different default view**.

You can use the [`DisplayMode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCalendars.TCustomCalendarView.DisplayMode) property for that purpose:

> Indicates the initial display mode.
>
> `DisplayMode` is an enumerated property with the following values:
>
> - Month
> - Year
> - Decade
>
> This property indicates the initial display mode and shows the current display mode when a user interacts with the control. To change the display mode, you can reset the `DisplayMode` property programmatically.

Comment: IOW: Read The Fine Manual. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis well, to be fair, the documentation I quoted is not easy to find. There is no mention of `TCalendarView` in any of past few "What's New" notes, and Marco's blogs about this component don't mention its actual class name. I don't have recent IDE versions installed, so it took me awhile to hunt down its class name, and a code example to learn what unit it is in, and only then could I track down the documentation for that unit in the DocWiki and thus find the component's documentation. The DocWiki's search engine is horribly crappy and is rarely useful in finding anything meaningful.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis On the other hand, since the OP has the component installed, hopefully he can just select the component in the IDE and press F1 and magically see the correct documentation appear? Who knows.

Comment: He already found the TCalendarView (he is already using it). So it should be easy to find the docs, either with F1 or online, e.g. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_the_Calendar_View

Comment: @RudyVelthuis if you actually read that page you just linked to, it doesn't explain HOW to switch views, except by user action at runtime. And there is no link to the actual documentation for the `TCalendarView` component (which is at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCalendars.TCalendarView). That is what took me awhile to hunt down in order to discover the existence of the `DisplayMode` property.  So, their documentation and its organization needs a lot of work.

Comment: yeah, well, but it is findable, if you know the name of the component. <g>